# Trying to filter out unique values in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Hi is there a way to filter out unique values ina a pandas data frame.
I am using the code below to filter out the unique values. However, I am getting different ordered combinations. For example, ['Creative, Modern Cuisine', 'Modern Cuisine, Creative'] is there a way to filter this out.

[[image: Part of the data]]

```
cuisine = df.Cuisine.unique()
cuisine_count = df.Cuisine.nunique()
print(cuisine, cuisine_count)
```

Comment: `cuisine  = cuisine.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Though, it sounds like the real issue is in how your dataframe is formatted, can you provide a couple sample lines from it?

Comment: @BeRT2me yea this is part of the data set I am working on Cuisine
Creative, Modern Cuisine
Creative
Creative
Creative
Modern Cuisine, Creative
Classic French
Classic French, Creative
Modern French, Creative
Classic French
Creative
Creative
Classic French
French
Modern Cuisine
Modern British
Modern French
French
Creative, Contemporary
Taizhou
Vegetarian
Cantonese
French Contemporary I am try to only get the unique values

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi sorry, @BeRT2me. I uploaded a part of the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intent, you are trying to get a list of all distinct cuisines which appear in your DataFrame. Try this:

```
df['Cuisine'].str.split(',').explode().str.strip().unique().tolist()
```

Explanation:

- `df['Cuisine'].str.split(',')`: split `Cuisine` strings at commas, producing a Series with a Python list in each row, where each list item holds an individual cuisine string
- [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html): for each list of cuisine strings, transform each string to a row
- `.str.strip()`: strip whitespace
- `.unique().tolist()`: get list of unique cuisines